# jquery does not work after update to new version

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of jQuery code in cakephp, and when i update jquery version, these functions does not work anymore.
On jquery 1.6.4. -> works, until 1.8.0. but on versions after 1.8.0 does not work.

```
$("#mytable tbody>tr:#person0").clone(true).attr('id','person'+lastRow).removeAttr('style').insertBefore("#mytable tbody>tr:#trAdd");
```

In console i see error with newer versions of jquery:

Syntax error, unrecognized expression:  tbody>:#person0

I try next, but does not work.

```
$("#mytable>tbody>tr:#person0")
$("#mytable.tbody.tr:#person0")
```

Are there some new rules from 1.8.0 jquery?

I googled but i cant find nothing smart?

Thank you,

Comment: What for `:` is in selector?

Comment: I have never seen a colon `:` used like you're using it.

Comment: @JayBlanchard the interesting thing is that it's the second time when I hear that incorrect selector works in 1.6, but causes an error in newer version. Looks like validator now throws an error instead of silently omitting an error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just not the right way of selecting an element.

You should try:

```
$("#mytable>tbody>tr#person0")
```

Without the `:`.

Ofcourse you can also just do what [AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51685/akx) said, and only use the `#person0` id, since it *should be* unique in the document.

Answer (score 4):

`#person0` is an ID selector in the first place, so the selector can be simplified into `"#person0"` if your HTML markup is valid.

After all, as we all know, ["there must not be multiple elements in a document that have the same id value."](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id) I suspect jQuery is now more strict in its parsing.

Comment: Well, even though multiple same IDs are strongly discouraged, they work: [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/s63nytn6/). Thus I strongly doubt that it is the reason for error.

Comment: @Regent not if you set simple ID selector  http://jsfiddle.net/s63nytn6/1/ ..only one will be found

Comment: @charlietfl still first will be found, not causing any errors. I pointed to fact, that multiple same IDs do not cause syntax error.

Comment: @Regent I suspect jQuery falls back to using `document.getElementById` when it recognizes a selector of the regexp form `^#[^ ]+$` (i.e. a hash and any string without spaces), and uses its own selector engine (that happens to support multiple els with the same ID) otherwise.